# FFmpeg: av_interleaved_write_frame doesn't detect failure for TLS output

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec, libavformat

How can I detect failure from `av_interleaved_write_frame`/`av_write_frame` when the output uses TLS and the connection fails?  Both functions continue to return 0 after the destination becomes unavailable.  When TLS isn't used, the functions detect the failure immediately and return -ve return codes.

**TLS output:**

```
av_interleaved_write_frame st.tb=90000, result=0
```

**Non-TLS output:**

```
av_interleaved_write_frame failed result=-32 - Broken pipe
```

This behaviour can also be demonstrated using the command-line tool.

**Expected Result for plain connection - Connection failure terminates program:**

```
$ ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://<rtsp_source>:554... -vcodec copy -an -f rtsp "rtsp://<rtsp_dest>:1935..."
ffmpeg version N-68044-g9f9440b Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov 27 2014 03:13:44 with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 15.100 / 54. 15.100
  libavcodec     56. 13.100 / 56. 13.100
  libavformat    56. 15.100 / 56. 15.100
  libavdevice    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
  libavfilter     5.  2.103 /  5.  2.103
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://<rtsp_source>:554...':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
    comment         : <comment>
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.011000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Data: none
Output #0, rtsp, to 'rtsp://<rtsp_dest>:1935...':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
    comment         : <comment>
    encoder         : Lavf56.15.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264, yuv420p, 1920x1080, q=2-31, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[rtsp @ 0000000004d4e940] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 0, current: 0; changing to 1. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Broken pipe00:00:15.71 bitrate=N/A
frame=  476 fps= 33 q=-1.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:15.77 bitrate=N/A
video:2178kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Conversion failed!
$
```

**Unexpected result for TLS connection - Program continues to run, although it knows something is wrong:**

```
$ ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://<rtsp_source>:554... -vcodec copy -an -f rtsp "rtsps://<rtsps_dest>:443..."
ffmpeg version N-68044-g9f9440b Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov 27 2014 03:13:44 with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 15.100 / 54. 15.100
  libavcodec     56. 13.100 / 56. 13.100
  libavformat    56. 15.100 / 56. 15.100
  libavdevice    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
  libavfilter     5.  2.103 /  5.  2.103
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://<rtsp_source>:554...':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
    comment         : <comment>
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.025000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Data: none
Output #0, rtsp, to 'rtsps://<rtsps_dest>:443...':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
    comment         : <comment>
    encoder         : Lavf56.15.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264, yuv420p, 1920x1080, q=2-31, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[rtsp @ 0000000002d5aa20] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 0, current: 0; changing to 1. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[tls @ 00000000056adc00] Error in the push function. bitrate=N/A
[tls @ 00000000056adc00] The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
    Last message repeated 2 times
[tls @ 00000000056adc00] The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
    Last message repeated 31 times
[tls @ 00000000056adc00] The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
    Last message repeated 89 times
[tls @ 00000000056adc00] The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
    Last message repeated 30 times
[tls @ 00000000056adc00] The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
    Last message repeated 92 times
[tls @ 00000000056adc00] The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
    Last message repeated 29 times
[tls @ 00000000056adc00] The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
    Last message repeated 90 times
[tls @ 00000000056adc00] The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
    Last message repeated 29 times
[tls @ 00000000056adc00] The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
    Last message repeated 92 times
...
```

I need to be able to detect the failure in `av_interleaved_write_frame` so that I can re-initiate the connection.

Comment: Any luck with this one?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  I ended up having to detect the failure from the other end and send a separate message back to re-initiate the connection.

Comment: I see. Thanks anyway